# If I want everything to execute, in order, inside a function, do I await each line?

Tags: dart

I know for sure my brain isn't totally clear on async/await so I need some clarity. I see a lot of examples where await is used on some lines and not others inside a function marked async. For example, I rarely if ever have seen an example like this (I am using the print statement as an example of something simple/basic.):

```
myFunction() async {
  await functionA();
  await print("This really long thing that's going to print out.");
  await functionB();
  await MyExtraClass.lookupSomethingQuickly();
  ...
}
```

So the examples I see it's usually something like this:

```
myFunction() async {
  await functionA();
  print("This really long thing that's going to print out.");
  await functionB();
  MyExtraClass.lookupSomethingQuickly();
  ...
}
```

So I am wondering if there's just an assumption that simple things will complete in order or if theoretically, putting await in front of each line is what I should be doing in cases where I absolutely need line 1 to follow line 2 to follow line 3, etc... Like what if I absolutely need that print to finish before functionB() goes off?

Essentially I find myself making a judgment call on every line every time I am writing a function with async/await and I never know if my code is working because of good timing and luck or if there would ever be cases that would throw the execution off.

Answer (score 5):

`async` / `await` is to make asynchronuos code easier to write, to read and to reason about. Synchronuos code doesn't need such support.
For async programming in Dart see also https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/futures/

If you take this code example

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
void main() {
  doSomethingAsync().then((_) => print('afterwards'));
  print('at last');
}

Future doSomethingAsync() {
  return new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    print('done something');
  });
}
```

Try it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/27f44ac91986dad3f336)

which prints

> at last
>   done something
>   afterwards

If you're not familiar with async execution this might be surprising

This is because code passed to `Future.delayed()` is executed with a delay of 1 second. The `Future` instance returned by `doSomethingAsync()` "completes" when the code in `Future.delayed()` has been executed.

In this line

```
doSomethingAsync().then((_) => print('afterwards'));
```

we call `.then(...)` on the `Future` returned by `doSomethingAsync()` and pass a closure (inline function) to `.then(...)`. (`(_) => print('afterwards')`).

A feature of `Future` is that it calls the code passed to `then(...)` after it was completed (in our case when `done something` was printed after 1 sec delay).

So the execution goes something like

- call `doSomethingAsync()` which schedules a call to `print('done something)` for later execution and returns a `Future`
- call `print('at last');` which just prints `at last`
- after 1 second delay `print('done something')` is called
- the `Future` returned from `doSomethingAsync()` is completed
- the `Future` calls `(_) => print('afterwards')
- `main()` ends.

When we use `async` / `await` the code looks like

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
Future main() async {
  await doSomethingAsync();
  print('afterwards');
  print('at last');
}

Future doSomethingAsync() {
  return new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    print('done something');
  });
}
```

Try it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/d8a9148c57b389650e53)

When run, the output is

> done something
>   afterwards
>   at last

we also could use `async` / `await` in `doSomethingAsync()` but now we only focus on `main()`

Now the execution looks like

- call `doSomething()` and wait for the returned `Future` to complete
- `print('done something')` is executed and the `Future` completed
- the execution of code after `await` continues
- `print('afterwards');`
- `print('at last');`

This is probably the behavior you expected.

To your original question. `await` is only necessary when a call returns a `Future` and you want the following code only be executed when the `Future` was completed. If the call doesn't return a `Future` there is nothing to wait for.

`await print('xxx')` is still valid code. This is to support functions that sometimes do some async work and return a `Future` but sometimes the don't have async work to do and execute the code immediately and just return afterwards. In this case there is nothing to wait for.

```
someTimesAsync() {
  if(new DateTime.now().weekday == 1) {
    return new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      print('done something');
    });
  } else {
    print('done something');
  }
}
```

```
await someTimesAsync();
```

works in both cases. If it wouldn't this would be cumbersome.

For more details about `async` / `await` see also https://www.dartlang.org/articles/await-async/

Comment: As usual I really appreciate your reply. This has helped me understand a bit better and is probably the best explanation I've read thus far. I wanted to follow up on when you said "If the call doesn't return a future, then there's nothing to wait for."

I think I have trouble with this when I use my own functions inside other functions. Should I be returning a Future when one of my functions might take some time to complete (i.e. ranking 1000 tennis players)? If I do not return a Future, then will the code that uses this function automatically wait?

Comment: Not sure whether this is a question. I would explain it this way. If you tell someone to do a task and to contact you when he is done and you do busy waiting until he comes back to you, this is what `await` is for. If you say to someone, reach me this thing and he hands the thing to you immediately, then there is no waiting because you didn't even have the chance to do anything in between. Then you don't need `await` because the action was completed in "one step".

Comment: That helps and I feel I am closer to understanding. I think I'm stuck on what is "immediately." So what about this scenario: Say I have a function that sums up a million random numbers -- a simple running like total += r and it returns total. And then I have another function that returns the sum of just 3 random numbers like return r1+r2+r3. For both cases I absolutely need the total before proceeding. In my brain I am thinking "I need to await on the first function because it might take longer but maybe not on the second because it's fast."  Can you tell me how my thinking is wrong?

Comment: The difference is that an async call is pushed into the event queue. `new Future(() => doSomething())` pushes `() => doSomething()` into the event queue for later execution. Then the next statement is processed. When there is nothing more to do, then JavaScript checks the event queue if there are scheduled tasks and then it takes one and processed until completed and so on. When you wait for something to be completed that was pushed into the event queue for later execution, then you use `await`.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your assistance with this. I worked with some of my code today and it really helped me clarify everything!